# Employer wants to leave me hanging and select the other one co-worker as a software developer

Tags: software-development, india, probation, fresher

I have been in this company as a trainee software developer for a month now. I am on probation period for training. The coworker joined the company on the same date and he is from the same university but from a different department(Computer Department) and I am from Electronics and Communication. We are working as a software developer on C#. The thing is I finished my assigned task at a given time with very good effort and the other co-worker takes more to finish his and still has lots of bugs in his code even if he has easier tasks. Sometimes I have to help him out to make the application up and running.

Our manager has good relation with me. He told me a few days ago that our IT executive only wants one developer and they are planning to choose another co-worker even if he doesn't know much about coding and development. I still am fresher so when my probation period gets finished I will be getting kicked out. Every IT senior developers in the company now know about this thing. They even told me that "you are good at what you are doing keep it up."

What should I do? Should I talk about this situation to the IT executive? Should I start looking for another job and leave? I like this company so much because everyone pays respect and it has a very good working environment.

I am from India.

---

**update:**

I asked for a solution to this situation to my manager and they said you can talk directly to your IT executive which I had already done. The IT executive said to me that"the other Co-worker interacted with me earlier and he said many things about you. Like you don't work hard, you don't know much of coding, etc." I know these accusations are false. The other co-worker is saying false things about me to the IT executive and they don't know it.

What should I do? Should I tell the truth to the IT executive, or should I put some bugs and errors in the co-worker's code when I help him or should I just go to his desk and confront him?

---

**update2:**

I have talked to the IT executive that my co-worker is lying about me and I have done my all task on time I have shown all my weekly timeline sheets to them. They said if you are right then we will investigate this situation and if he was lying to me then we will take strict action against him."

Comment: If they’ve already acknowledged that the other person is not as good at coding/development, and they think you’re good at your job, *and they’re planning not to keep you on anyway*, then there’s not really anything you can do to change their minds. Whatever reasons they have, they’re not ones you can change.

Comment: Do you know why they like the other person better? Do you have a brash personality? Are you bad at communicating? Some of those soft skills are highly prized in companies. It's not always about coding. In any case, yes, look for another job. This is the reason they're telling you this now. They don't want you to be blindsided when you're let go. You really need to find something else. Their message couldn't be clearer.

Comment: The other person never interacts with anyone ever. and I always communicate with others with good manners even if they are rude because I don't want to lose my job for that reason.

Comment: "`should I put some bugs and errors in the co-worker's code when I help him`" ???? Seriously???!!!! Any sympathy which I had for you has just flown out the window. Way to screw up your life

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are under probation you should certainly keep your eyes out for other jobs.

Don't worry about the difference in quality of work. There may be many reasons why they may choose them over you. It no point trying to understand it, because you can't change their mind.

If you are well respected by your manager, there is absolutely no problem with you going to them and seeing if he can find other opportunities in the organisation for you. A good manager will do what's best for the organisation, and that includes retaining good people.

It's not disrespectful for them not to employ you after probation. Provided they are honest with you every step of the way, that is the main thing.

---

**Update for the update**

First of all, don't sabotage your coworkers work.

Yes, you absolutely should have, when the executive made those claims, defended yourself by stating that you manager is happy with your work. You then could have raised that there is an obvious conflict of interest there.

You should go to your manager and speak to them about this. If they don't want to discuss it with you, then they don't respect you, and they don't respect the organisation. The executive is already showing very questionable judgement by not avoiding the clear conflict of interest.

If your manager is very concerned that the executive is making decisions on the basis of the assessments made by the candidates, then that is a good sign, and maybe your manager speak with the executive and ensure they have a clear idea of your capability.

And you should continue to look for other jobs.

Comment: I think you are right

Comment: I think you are I shouldn't confront him I should talk to the manager again and also clear out my accusation to with IT executive and show my all of the work if that help then ok. In the meantime, I will look for another job too. I think confronting him won't take me anywhere.

Answer (score -7):

> Should I start looking for another job and leave?

Yes, I would be looking at another job where you can do what you want.

> and also I like this company so much because everyone pays respect and it has a very much good working environment.

Your question and this statement conflict with one another. How can they be respectful towards you but at the same time not give you the job you desire? That doesn't sound like a respectful relationship that you describe. Everyone being "nice" doesn't really matter if you're not doing what you want and getting the pay you deserve.

> He told me a few days ago that our IT executive only wants one developer and they are planning to choose another co-worker even if he doesn't know much about coding and development.

So basically your manager said even though you know what you're doing, he's not going to select you over the other guy who doesn't know anything? Again, all this doesn't sound right to me and a large chunk of the story is missing.

It could be a hint that your manager is gearing you up for another gig, possibly. But I would suspect that they wouldn't be secretive about this and would tell you up front. I would go sit with the manager and have a one-on-one about what your expectations are and what the place can offer you and what they need from you to get there.

> Our manager has good relation with me.

I would go to your manager with an ultimatum (don't tell him you're going to quit though, but do make a very strong statement that you want to be a C# developer). Tell him that you are hoping to get a job as a C# developer and you don't want anything else. You did all your work, you helped your co-worker succeed, and you want a job in coding. If he says no, then start looking for another job, and turn in your notice.

Comment: The thing is I am doing the work that they wanted and I don't think so that any company will appreciate that I do whatever I want. And another thing is that I said my IT senior gives respects for my work I don't know about IT executives because they don't interact with us that much(like once or twice in week).

Comment: Dan, we're not taking away the same thing from the OP. I feel that your answer may have been to hastily formulated. You're correct to state that the company (as a consequence of a decision made by the 'IT executive') isn't acting respectfully. But there is no conflict with OP's statement that colleagues are generally respectful and appreciative. Similarly, you seem to conflate the decisions and actions of OP's manager with those of a higher-up executive. We really don't know what's happening: The manager clearly doesn't have hiring authority, the other hire may have connections to an executive

Comment: It could simply come down to the job in question requires a specific degree, or there is indeed more to the story, both are likely true.  I would caution against resigning as an trainee unless the position is a full-time permanent position (does not sound like it is).